# Как в профиле wp вывести все свои комментарии через плагин wpDiscuz

Tags: wordpress

Привети всем, есть страница автора и там хочу выввести все комментарии которые сделал автор, также установлен плагин/система комментаривания wpDiscuz, может есть какой-то хук или шорткод для вывода последних комментариев пользователя у себя на странице автора в стиле который предлогает плагин wpDiscuz?

Comment: Вам проще будет узнать это у разработчиков плагина... Тут люди ленивые, они скорее в базу данным постучат и получат всё что надо, чем будут читать документацию и разбираться, где-там та функция...

Comment: В wpDiscuz нет необходимого Вам функционала. Он просто не работает таким образом. Все это вешается на comments_template(), если я не ошибаюсь, что выводит форму для комментирования и сами комментарии к конкретной записи (это же вроде можно сделать и шорткодом). С страницей автора это не будет работать тем образом которым Вам бы хотелось.

Comment: @BlackStar1991 да ладно Вам, просто время или желание давать развернутые ответы или лезть в документацию не всегда есть, при том что верные ответы в итоге в большинстве случаев не принимают. Стучатся в БД обычно в последнюю очередь, только когда это оправдано.

Comment: Есть соответствующий топик на их [форуме поддержки](https://wpdiscuz.com/community/troubleshooting/show-comments-per-user-in-their-page/) и [еще один](https://wpdiscuz.com/community/troubleshooting/how-to-output-all-comments-and-subcomments-by-user-id/)